# error calling textView by id "texst1 cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Tags: android, xml, android-viewpager

I'm trying to call a text view from a fragment in my view pager, but I'm having a problem as Eclipse gives me the following error

> texst1 cannot be resolved or is not a field

I've tried closing the IDE and restarting it, and I also tried deleting the R file and the same error exists. Can you help me figure it out?

```
public static class DemoObjectFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_OBJECT = "object";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_collection_object, container, false);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        TextView x=((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.texst1));
        x.setText(Integer.toString(args.getInt(ARG_OBJECT))+"test");
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check your xml files, there might be some errors preventing the R file from being generated.

Answer (score 0):

check your `xml` for errors, if there is any error maybe you can not see(no red line), think what was your last thing that you did with xml **before** error. also you can clean project.

Answer (score 0):

The text view is presumably part of your own layout not an Android system layout, so you should replace this:

TextView x=((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.texst1));

With this:
TextView x=((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.texst1));

Answer (score 0):

You did everything right except referencing the id of the TextView.

You have:

`TextView x=((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.texst1));`

It should be:

`TextView x=((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.texst1));`

Referencing Android is unnecessary as you are referencing your own layout rather than an Android supplied layout.

I hope this works for you!